# Dependent picklist field on Salesforce for Outlook side panel

Tags: picklist, outlook

I am creating Case from Side panel at MS Outlook. In the case object I have 2 dependent picklist fields which I am trying to expose on Side Panel. I am using Publisher action to create case and not configuring anything in "Outlook Configuration under Desktop Administration". The strange behavior found that dependent picklist is not properly working on side panel which are correctly working either in console or standard page layout.
By the way, case is getting successfully created without those dependent picklist fields.

My question is if it is a bug or is there any workaround of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your dependent picklist is in less number, or for outlook you will need less number of picklist values. You can create third picklist with combination of two, eg, Picklist1-Picklist2. When the case is created fire a workflow which will check for value in third picklist and fill the first picklist and its dependent picklist.

Comment: I have 3 dependent picklists Picklist1-Picklist2-Picklist3. I want same behavior as it is happening in Standard page layouts.

Comment: Not sure if Salesforce sidepanel for Outlook will use function properly for dependent picklist. Is the Picklist huge?

Comment: Yes. first picklist contains 8 values, 2nd one 25 values, 3rd one 10 values